# Resizing parent window after child sizes change

Tags: c++, qt, layout

I have been messing with this problem for hours, and decided it's time to ask SO :)

I have a Qt program that rotates an image and then updates the size of the widget. Here is the code I'm using to do this currently.

```
void VideoSubWindow::showFrame(const QImage& frame)
{
    QPixmap pixmap = QPixmap::fromImage(frame);
    ui->videoFrameLabel->setPixmap(pixmap);
    resizeWidgets(pixmap.size());
}

void VideoSubWindow::resizeWidgets(const QSize &size)
{
    if(frameSize != size)
    {
        frameSize = size;
        ui->videoFrameLabel->setFixedSize(size);
        ui->scrollArea->setMinimumSize(size.width() + 2, size.height() + 2);
    }
}
```

The widgets are structured as follows:

```
VideoSubWindow (QMainWindow)
 -> centralWidget (QWidget) (Vertical layout is set on this)
   -> scrollArea (QScrollArea)
     -> videoFrameLabel (QLabel)
   -> statusBar (QStatusBar)
   -> menuBar (QMenuBar)
```

When the code above is executed, like rotating the image 90 degrees, the image will be rotated, but the window doesn't resize to fit the new pixmap size. I have tried to call `adjustSize()` and `updateGeometry()` on `SubWindow` and `centralWidget`, but those seem to have zero effect. But, if I manually resize the window with my mouse, the window snaps to the minimum size that was set for the `scrollArea`, so that seems to be taking effect.

Does anyone have experience with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try with the `resize(...)` function : [Qt documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#size-prop)

`adjustSize()` used `sizeHint()` function, so calling `adjustSize()` on SubWindow and centralWidget cannot have any effet

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I tried resizing both `centralWidget` and `VideoSubWindow` using the `scrollArea` size but no change :-\

Comment: I may not understand what you are trying to do, but you should try to resize the scrollArea...

Comment: I tried this yesterday, but still no joy :( I'm not sure how to get the window to size when the image size changes.